# Cucumber java Tagging- Runner class not getting failed if we pass incorrect name of tagging in Cucumber options

Tags: cucumber

I have created one feature file and tagged it and configure it in runner class while executing the runner class it's not getting failed even though passing the incorrect name of tagging in cucumber options[here is the snapshot for more clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9e6u.png)

Comment: There is a message that mentions the tag option supplied are incorrect. What kind of failure u are looking for and what purpose?

Comment: On the left, the runner class got passed, even though the tag is supplied is incorrect. The runner class should fail while supplied incorrect tags, how I can manage this situation If somebody mistakenly added the space or somehow the letter append with the tags and execute the runner class, all feature got executed successfully and they push the code on the repository,

Comment: They should check the generated report after test run before checking in code. Pretty clearly it mentions no scenarios run